# Edit woocommerce_product_archive_description using hook

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to customize the category description in woocommerce. I see that the hook is `woocommerce_product_archive_description`, but I'm not able to get the category description,I will get the product description instead. Did I miss something in my code?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description','woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description','woocommerce_product_archive_description', 10 );

function theme_woocommerce_product_archive_description()
  {
    ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <?php the_excerpt(); // this will give me the wrong result ?>
      </div>
    <?php
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description','theme_woocommerce_product_archive_description', 10 );
```

Comment: `the_excerpt()` outputs the post excerpt. It's not for category descriptions. You need to use `the_archive_description()`.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help I will give a try.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's correct, but it works

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'wp_kama_woocommerce_archive_description_action', 5 );
function wp_kama_woocommerce_archive_description_action(){
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $term->description = 'asdf';
}
```